# 3D rendering medicine box

Tags: software-recommendation

What is the best and simplest software to nicely 3D render medicine box out of the die art with different dimensions? (customizable dimension) . Something like this:
http://www.bayerandina.com/images/negocios/fotos_productos/CC/ecuador/foto_asa500ecu.jpg

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By far, Esko is your best choice for die-line based 3D software. IMHO.

If you aren't concerned about the details of the carton folds and you can accept a simple cube showcasing the the artwork, then any 3d application will do. Your sample image appears to be a simple chamfered box without a lot of detail when it comes to the closures, creases etc. If that's ok for you again, even the most rudimentary 3d software can accomplish this.

Esko excels at taking a true flat dieline and enables you to fold it at specific edges resulting in a realistic and precise model, something that even popular, high-end 3d software does not normally integrate.

https://www.esko.com/en/